# How to generate the Sierpinski Triangle

Tags: java

For this class, I have to generate the SierpinskiTriangle by using loop and arraylist. This is what I have done so far; however, I don't know how to do the loop. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

```js
public ArrayList<Oval> createASierpinskiTriangle() {
  int no_points  =  new Input().readIntDialog("Please enter number of points");
  if(no_points<1||no_points>MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_POINTS){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid value entered. Please enter from 1 to "+MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_ROWS);
  }
  ArrayList<Oval> list = new ArrayList<Oval>();
  int x1 = 250, y1 = 50;
  int x2 = 100, y2 = 350;
  int x3 = 350, y3 = 350;
  
  Random rand = new Random();
  // start point
  int x = x1, y = y1;
  
  // loop
  
  // Select randomly one of the vertices
  int v = rand.nextInt(3) + 1; // 1, 2, or 3
  // next point
  
  
  // half way between the current point and the selected vertex
  if (v == 1) {
   x = (x + x1)/2;
   y = (y + y1)/2;
  } else if (v == 2) { //...
   x = (x + x2)/2;
   y = (y + y2)/2;
   
  } else { // v is 3
   x = (x + x3)/2;
   y = (y + y3)/2;
  }
  Oval oval = new Oval(x-2,y-2,4,4,Color.BLUE,true);
  list.add(oval);
  
  // end of the loop
  
  return list;
 }
```

Comment: What kind of loop where you planning on? Do you just want to generate `N` number of `Ovals`? If so, use a regular for loop.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please use the snippet only for javascript (see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)